# The value returned must have the same type as the function return type?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

> **Every return in a function with a return type other than void must
>   return a value. The value returned must have the same type as the
>   function return type, or must have a type that can be implicitly
>   converted to that type.** - *C++ Primer*

```
struct Person 
{
   const std::string & getName() const { return name; }
   std::string name;
};
```

Q: In function `getName()`, does the valued returned have the same type as the function return type?

Comment: Yup, it sure does.

Comment: Imagine you asked a waiter, "Is the food I'm served the same as I've ordered?" The waiter would feel strange but the question would still made sense. Then, you asked, "If so, why?" The waiter would feel confused.

Comment: @NickyC Well, I know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the value returned be regarded as the same type as the function return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366469/can-the-value-returned-be-regarded-as-the-same-type-as-the-function-return-type)

Comment: Note that the duplicate is of the same author.

Answer (score 1):

```
const std::string & getName() const { return name; }
```

This function returns a *reference* to `name`.

> A reference is a simple reference datatype that is less powerful but safer than the pointer type inherited from C. The definition of a reference in C++ is such that it does not need to exist. It can be implemented as a new name for an existing object (similar to rename keyword in Ada).

For more details, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: yeah, I know. so they can be regarded as the same type, right?

Comment: @J.mox They have differences. References are more like pointers, but safer. I suggest you don't have to read book word by word. You'll get better understanding after you write enough codes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: In function `getName()`, does the valued returned have the same type as the function return type?

Yes. Otherwise, the compiler will let you know. If the compiler does not complain, you can rest assured that it is able to return the correct type from whatever expression you used in the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

> In function `getName()`, does the valued returned have the same type as the function return type?

**YES** (otherwise the code would not compile).

`getName()` is declared as returning a `const std::string &`, which is a non-const *reference* to a const `std::string` object.

The `const` at the end of the `getName()` declaration means the `this` pointer inside of `getName()` is const, and so every member is also treated as const.

Since `this->name` is effectively a const `std::string`, and `getName()` returns a reference to a const `std::string`, the returned value indeed matches the return type.